# Random Scatter of the one object multiple times

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, 3d, photoshop-effects

Have only recently got into 3D design, found this image on google and wondered what software is used there is no way this designer scattered the pills one by one surely?

The pills them selves where obviously Created in C4D or something similar. But is there some sort of plugin to create that scatter effect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

Using any 3D software with animation engine you can achieve something like this, but again, not (*as easy*) in PS or AI.

> In **3DSMax** or **Blender** you just animate some pills falling and make a
>   collide surface and then just select a frame in the animation that
>   looks best after the pills have fallen on the surface.

Using PS just for minor color/shades adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if you can get your hands on C4D but you can duplicate the objects (like the pills) and then apply tags that make them fall and scatter naturally. then you can just freeze it and export a picture any size you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rigid Body Physics simulation.

The ground and text are set as passive objects, while the pills are active objects. Create the pills and raise them above the text then play the simulation until they settle into place, the gravity in the simulation makes them fall down while they collide and interact with each other. Once they are in place you can delete, rotate or move some of the pills until it all looks good.

Just a couple of minutes in blender I can get this -

[image: sample scene]

In [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRxF63ihxUk) a texture is added to the items so they make up a final image, [this is the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYL9w6xsZ6g) on how to make that. [This example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTUm7r5DiEg) has fun smashing up a building but you can see similar results at the end. Most 3D software includes or has access to physics simulations to get a similar result.